# plotting two cubes with diffrent porosity and permability with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

i want to plot two cubes with diffrent porosity and permability with MATLAB

i did this for plotting simple cubes

```
% Define the vertices and faces of the first cube
v1 = [-1 -1 -1; -1 -1 1; -1 1 1; -1 1 -1; 1 -1 -1; 1 -1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 -1];
f1 = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 1 4 8 5; 2 3 7 6; 1 2 6 5; 4 3 7 8];

% Define the vertices and faces of the second cube
v2 = [2 -1 -1; 2 -1 1; 2 1 1; 2 1 -1; 4 -1 -1; 4 -1 1; 4 1 1; 4 1 -1];
f2 = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 1 4 8 5; 2 3 7 6; 1 2 6 5; 4 3 7 8];

% Create a new figure
figure;

% Plot the first cube in red
patch('Faces',f1,'Vertices',v1,'FaceColor','r');

% Hold the plot
hold on;

% Plot the second cube in blue
patch('Faces',f2,'Vertices',v2,'FaceColor','b');
view(3);
```

Comment: How do you have your porosity and permeability data in variables? How exactly do you want them represented on the cubes?

Comment: A patch graphics object does not have porosity or permeability properties, a patch object is not a physical object. So you need to determine how you want to represent these properties graphically. Color? Transparency? Shininess?

Comment: You may want to read [Volume Visualization](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/volume-visualization.html). It will show you the different ways of representing 3D volumetric data (like porosity/permeability of a volume).